# Show that UPrime = {1^n : n ∈ N is prime} is in P

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I have this question to solve. According to my understanding, it basically requires a turing machine that outputs lines on the tape, with the number of the lines being any prime number.

My idea is to take the [AKS test's conclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) and making a case that since, calculating primes is a problem that can be solved in polynomial time complexity as already proven by AKS, hence this problem is also in P.

Is this the right way? what would be a more formal/mathematical way of expressing this if it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following algorithm:

- Input: number $n$ encoded in unary
- For $k$ from $2$ to $n-1$, check whether $k \mid n$, and if so, output "Not prime".
- Output "Prime".

This algorithm runs in time polynomial in $n$.

The AKS test, in contrast, runs in time polynomial in $\log n$, assuming that the input $n$ is encoded in binary. If the input is encoded in unary, the running time (at least on a multitape Turing machine) will be $O(n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There are a couple of things i don't understand though. 

Why do you count to n - 1? and what does $k∣n$ mean?

Comment: The notation “$k \mid n$” means “$k$ divides $n$”. I’ll let you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Notice that your input is unary.

Comment: if im not mistaken, your point is that since all unary numbers can be recognized by a turing machine in polynomial time, and all prime unaries are subset of all unary numbers, the complexity of the latter is also in P?

Comment: @Blitz Nope, that is not true in general. For example, there are undecidable unary languages. The point is that the unary representation of a number is _exponentially_ larger than a base-$k$ representation of the same number for $k \geq 2$. Consider the impact of this on your time complexity.